# ggplot2: Multiple Regression Lines in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame of 3 columns - Velocity, Height and Gender, respectively. I colour-coded the points based on Gender.

How can I plot two regression lines, one for each gender?

Comment: Look at `?geom_smooth`

Comment: You can find the answer here, with reproducible code:
[Cookbook for R](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Scatterplots_(ggplot2)/)

Answer (score 0):

You can group by factors

```
dat <- data.frame(Velocity = c(4,2,3,3,4,5), Height = c(2,4,5,6,8,9), Gender = c('M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F'))

g <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = Velocity, y = Height))
g <- g + geom_point(aes(col=Gender))
g <- g + geom_smooth(aes(group=Gender), method='lm')
g
```